# Javascript - Pull attribute into array/delete items based on attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I want to pull into an array the classes of all of the `<img>` in a particular `<div>` and then use those classes to delete the first `<img>` that shares that class in a different `<div>`.

So far, I have this that calls the original array:

```
var class = $('.frame div img').each(function() {
    return $(this).class;
}).get();

class.forEach(function(entry) {
    console.log(entry);
});
```

The log outputs a list of the `<img></img>` lines.

After that, I get stuck.

```
//Iterate through array and delete first <img> in #grid that has the same class, limit one per iteration.

// var img_class = $.each(class, function(key, value) {
//     console.log(value);
//     return $(this).attr('class');
// });

$('#grid img').each(function(){
    if($(this).attr('class') == img_class){
        $(this).remove();
    }
});
```

The goals are:

- Getting an array of classes into the img_class variable
- Delete only the first `<img>` as it iterates through each class in the array

Thanks!

Comment: It makes no sense why you are using each() that is doing nothing. You are treating the `each()` like it is `map()`

Comment: There should not be multiple dom elements sharing the same id!

Comment: Um, `id` is supposed to be unique within an HTML document.

Comment: Alright. How can I do this with class?

Comment: If you're writing in HTML5, consider using a `data-xxx` attribute, where the `xxx` is the unique-within-div identifier.  You can then do something with `getElementsByTagName("img")`.  Someone more familiar with jQuery will need to help with the details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to use some other attribute than class, eg. 'data-type'.

With the collected attribute values (e.g. 'types' array) do:

```
var $grid = $('#grid');

// iterate over collected types
types.forEach(function(type)) {

    // find within $grid the first <img> with data-type == type and remove it from DOM
    $grid.find('img[data-type="' + type + '"]:eq(0)').remove();
}
```

You could also do all in one rush:

```
// iterate over source <img> set
$('.frame div img').each(function() {

 // get current images type-attrib
 var type = $(this).attr('data-type');

 // find within $grid the first <img> with data-type == type and remove it from DOM
 $grid.find('img[data-type="' + type + '"]:eq(0)').remove();

});
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understood it right but would something like this be of any help?

```
var firstIDs = "";

$('.frame div img').each(function() {

    firstIDs += $(this).attr('id') + ",";

});

var SplitIDs = firstIDs.split(",");

$('#grid img').each(function(){

    for(var i = 0; i < SplitIDs.length; i++) {

        if($(this).attr('id') == SplitIDs[i]){

            $("#grid img #"+$(this).attr('id')+":first").remove();

        }

    }

});
```

Comment: Thanks! It's super close! The only problem is that the `remove()` function is being applied to every `img` with that ID instead of just one.

Comment: Can you get the idea from my updated answer? :) Not sure if that precise selector fits to your HTML.

Comment: I'm trying to but I still am having issues. SplitIDs is returning an array like this: `["1001", "103", "104", ""]` and if I place `console.log($(this).attr('id'))` within the if statement it outputs `103`, `104`, `104`. `1001` is not present within `#grid`. The code is deleting lines but it is still applying to all divs with, for example, id = 104 instead of just one. I very much appreciate your help! : )

Comment: Can you tell me the id of the div from where you want to delete lines? :)

Comment: `#grid` contains `<img>` to be deleted. So once I changed `#grid img #` to `#grid #` it started deleting the lines. Just more than I wanted : )

Comment: Try #grid #id:first :) Or last if that is better. Or did you notice the latest $("#grid img #"+$(this).attr('id')).remove();?

Comment: I'm using the latest. I tried this, but it's throwing an unexpected token error: `$("#grid img #"+$(this).attr('id'):first).remove();`...

Comment: Thanks for your help! +1. I was able to get fast's to work with some tweaking.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(function() {
    var classes = $.map($(".frame div img"), function(v, k) {
      return [$(v).attr("class")];
    });
    var d = [];
    console.log($("#grid img").length);
    $.each($("#grid img"), function(k, v) {
        if ( classes.hasOwnProperty($(v).attr("class")) ) {
              d.push(v); $("body").find($(d.slice(0, 1))).remove();
            };    
    });
    console.log($("#grid img").length);
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/yv95C/